# reactjs how to implement server-side filtration of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have to get a users from backend and push the result array into a property of third-party component. I can't push the result into the component's state, like `setUsersList`, because it leads to infinity render-loop. So I decided to use a function which will put the data from backend into a variable and return variable's value.

```
<InputAutocomplete
  ...
  value={selectedUserName}
  onChange={(value: string) => setSelectedUserName(value)}
  options={getFilteredUsers(selectedUserName)}
/>
```

My function is:

```
const getFilteredUsers = (typedValue: any): any[] => {
  console.log('***getting into getFilteredUsers method')
  if (!typedValue) {
    return []
  }

  let usersList: any[]

  repository.GetUsers(typedValue).then((response) => {
    if (response.StatusCode !== null) {
      response.Message.then((errorText) => showNotificationPopup(errorText, consts.ERROR_OCCURED, 'error'))
      return
    }

    response.Data.then((users) => {
      console.log('filling usersList')
      usersList = (users.map((u) => {
          return {key: u.Id, value: `${u.Name} - ${u.Position} - ${u.DopOfficeName}` }
        })
      )
    })
  })

  console.log('leaving function')
  return usersList
}
```

It works unacceptable for me (although it works as expected):

1. ***getting into getFilteredUsers method
2. leaving function (with empty array)
3. filling usersList (too late)

The property "options" of third's party component doesn't accept `Promise<any[]>`, it can only accept `any[]`, thus I can't mark my function as `async` and await the result from repository before to leave the function.
How to prevent leaving function before I'll get the result?
Maybe I've made a wrong decision at all. If I'm wrong I need a help, how to implement server-side refilling of autocomplete input component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't push the result into the component's state, like setUsersList, because it leads to infinity render-loop

This should not be the case.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {

    const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
    const [username, setUsername] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {

        if (!typedValue) return [];

        repository.GetUsers(typedValue).then((response) => {
            if (response.StatusCode !== null) {
                response.Message.then((errorText) => showNotificationPopup(errorText, consts.ERROR_OCCURED, 'error'));
                return;
            }

            response.Data.then((users) => {
                console.log('filling usersList');
                const usersList = users.map(u => {
                    return { key: u.Id, value: `${u.Name} - ${u.Position} - ${u.DopOfficeName}`};
                });
                setOptions(usersList);
            })
        })

        console.log('leaving function')

    }, [username]);

    return (
        <InputAutocomplete
            value={username}
            onChange={(value) => setUsername(value)}
            options={options}
        />
    );
};
```

Above code should not go in infinite loop.